# cannot verify signature uiautomator2-server-v4.270.apk'. Original error: The 'java.exe' binary could not be found neither in PATH nor under JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, android-studio, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-java

I'm beginner for Android Appium Automation, when i try kickstart my application through appium, I'm getting the following error, please someone Assist me get this done
Thanks in Advance

appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'. Original error: The 'java.exe' binary could not be found neither in PATH nor under JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\bin)

In my case Java installed in the following location
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361\bin\java.exe

and SDK Build Tools and command line tools are fine, still I'm not getting what mistake I'm doing

Comment: the post-8 version JDKs include the run-time, so at some point you installed the JDK for Java 19.  (in short, your PATH is set wrong)  See setting PATH for Java:  https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html  (you may have 2 entries for java_home... so check for multiples...)  This may be separate from the signature error, but not sure...  maybe see this link if you still see that: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/14724

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.